# django permissions for block ip addresses import Blocklist

Tags: python, django

In [django custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) for blocking ip addresses it seems its using some sort of model named `Blocklist` but I don't know how to import this model?

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlocklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blocked IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blocked = Blocklist.objects.filter(ip_addr=ip_addr).exists()
        return not blocked
```

Answer (score 1):

Its example. You need to create model Blocklist:

```
class Blocklist(models.Model):
    ip_addr = models.IPAddressField()
```

Then you need to add ip_addreses that are not alowed.

Comment: and where I can I read more about this, also examples are appreciated.

Comment: use `GenericIPAddressField()` instead, `IPAddressField` has been depreciated. @FarhangAmaji, there is nothing more you need to do just add the above in models.py, run migrations, and import it into your permissions file.